# how to merge column headers in a flex grid, similar to colspan in html?

Tags: apache-flex

I am looking into achieving below two features in a flex grid( or advanced grid).

**1.** merge column headers ( as in group just the cells in the header row ).
**2.** add multiple ( say 2 ) headers to the grid.

If you know any such examples pls help me with some link.

thanks.

(I am using flex 3)

Answer (score 6):

Found this link that exactly does what I want :)

http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/03/thinking_about_item_renderers_1.html
see section: Split Columns/Grouped Columns

Answer (score 2):

here is an example of column grouping

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- dpcontrols/adg/ColumnGroupADG.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            // Import the data used by the AdvancedDataGrid control. 
            include "SimpleFlatData.as";
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG"
        dataProvider="{dpFlat}"
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:groupedColumns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Region"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory_Rep"
                headerText="Territory Rep"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Revenues">    
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Actual"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Estimate"/>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>    
        </mx:groupedColumns>
   </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

link http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_09.html

Comment: actually I want to merge cells not grouping.
Merge cells as in - we can do in html by using rowspan.

Comment: @dotnetcoder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569311/how-do-you-merge-cells-in-a-flex-datagrid