# How do you merge cells in a Flex Datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

Is there any way to merge cells (vertically and/or horizontally) in a datagrid? At least, for example, is there a way to show that certain datagridcolumns belong to one group.

For example, I'll take three columns: column1, column2, column3.
All these three should be grouped to the Category cell with a rowspan of 3 -- a "super header" if you will.

Thanks, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should create a Split Header according to Alex Harui:

http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/03/thinking_about_item_renderers_1.html

http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/SplitColumns/dg.swf

Similarly, instead of trying to merge two cells horizontally: try splitting one cell into two cells using and itemRenderer for the dataGridColumn.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no. Let someone correct me, but I've gone through the trouble to write my own table control to get around this. The Grid has the span concept though.

That is, I mean horizontal grouping. The AdvancedDataGrid supports row-grouping, but I've never used it so I can't go into specific examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that a free MecGrid component solves this merging cells problem (it includes other cool features). But this custom component also misses a lot of other features found in standard FlexComponents.

http://code.google.com/p/flexspreadsheet/